# if statement to indicate whether a market has gone up or down

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

I have a dataset from library(ISLR) and I would like to make my own up and down, but my if statement always fail, any help would be appreciated:

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Smarket)

for (i in 1:nrow(Smarket)){
    Smarket$myown = ()
    if (Smarket[i, "Today"]>0) { Smarket$myown = "Up"
    } else { Smarket$myown = "Down"
  }
}
```

Please note that if I use the statement `ifelse` then the issue is solved, but I want your help to MODIFY the above code, so I may learn

```
 Smarket$myown = ifelse(Smarket[, "Today"]> 0, "Up", "Down")
```

Comment: You need to use the indicator `i` for writing the variable sto `myown`, e.g. `Smarket$myown[i] <- "Up"`. You will also need to remove the `Smarket$myown = ()` line as it's useless.

Comment: Thanks, Roman it was a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you're missing the indexing that will actually create the column you want. The `ifelse` works properly because it's doing the indexing for you. Try this instead:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Smarket)){
  if(Smarket[i, "Today"] > 0){ 
    Smarket$myown[i] = "Up"
  }else{ 
    Smarket$myown[i] = "Down"
  }
}
```

Notice that I didn't need to initialize the column "myown" like you did. If you were creating an entirely new vector you would need to, but since you're adding to an existing `data.frame`, it isn't necessary. Also note that each time you assign a new value to "myown" there is a `[i]`. Read it as:

"For every item in `nrow(Smarket)`, if the i'th "Today" value is greater than zero, store "Up" to in the i'th value of "myown". Else, store a "Down" in the i'th item of "myown".

Comment: thank you very much for a very clear explanation. It is an embarrassing error, but if I havent asked I would have not learned:)